# Parsing: extract a version from a html line

Tags: linux, text-processing, html

I would like to extract version number from this string:

```
<a href="/url/version/tree/1.0.1alpha11" class="css-truncate">
```

Note that '`/url/version/tree/`' may change (ex: from `/url/version/tree/` to `/url/version2/tree1/)` and version may change too (ex: from `1.01alpha11` to `2.0stable`)

Ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**`sed`** solution:

Sample file `input.txt`:

```
<a href="/url/version/tree/1.0.1alpha11" class="css-truncate">
<a href="/url/version2/tree1/1.0.2alpha11" class="css-truncate">
<a href="/url/version/tree/2.0stable" class="css-truncate">
```

---

```
sed -En 's@.*\<href="/[^[:space:]]+/([^/"[:space:]]+).*@\1@p' input.txt
```

The output:

```
1.0.1alpha11
1.0.2alpha11
2.0stable
```

Answer (score 0):

I extracted the version by using below awk command. As tested its worked fine.

```
Inputfile

<a href="/url/version/tree/1.0.1alpha11" class="css-truncate">
<a href="/url/version2/tree1/1.0.2alpha11" class="css-truncate">
<a href="/url/version/tree/2.0stable" class="css-truncate">
```

command

```
awk -F '[/]' '{print $NF}' Inputfile| awk -F '"' '{print $1}'
```

output

```
1.0.1alpha11
1.0.2alpha11
2.0stable
```

Answer (score 0):

Source file: input.txt:

```
<a href="/url/version2/tree1/2.0stable" class="css-truncate">
<a href="/url/version/tree/1.0.1alpha11" class="css-truncate">
<a href="/url/version2/tree1/1.0.2alpha11" class="css-truncate">
```

Using `awk` and `sed`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } { print $5 }' input.txt | sed -E 's/^(.*)"\s.*/\1/'
```

Results:

```
2.0stable
1.0.1alpha11
1.0.2alpha11
```